# Uncrustify: remove space between template angles doesn't work

Tags: c++, uncrustify

I'd like to remove space between template angles, for example:

```
void Function (list<list<int> >);
                             ^
                             |
              This space should be removed.
```

For this purpose I use `sp_angle_shift = remove`, but is has no effect.

```
$ uncrustify -c uncrustify.cfg function.h --no-backup -l CPP
```

Input

```
void Function (const list<list<T> > data);

void Function (const list<list<T> > data)
{
}
```

Output:  the same.

How to remove spaces between angles?

Comment: I'd recommend looking into clang-format: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

upgrade `uncrustify` to [0.60](https://sourceforge.net/projects/uncrustify/files/uncrustify/uncrustify-0.60/) and add/modify :

```
sp_angle_shift                           = remove
sp_permit_cpp11_shift                    = true
```

For your information :

```
# Add or remove space between '>' and '>' in '>>' (template stuff C++/C# only). Default=Add
sp_angle_shift                           = add      # ignore/add/remove/force

# Permit removal of the space between '>>' in 'foo<bar<int> >' (C++11 only). Default=False
# sp_angle_shift cannot remove the space without this option.
sp_permit_cpp11_shift                    = false    # false/true
```